# Request::Secure() not work with Asset()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a site that use both HTTP and HTTPS, i set the `asset('smt', Request::Secure())` to auto make HTTP or HTTPS type, but it not working.

I 've used `print_r(Request::Secure())` in HTTPS connect, my site shows '1' in body, but why it not work at asset?, the asset link only shown `'http://'`.

so i give `asset('smt', true)` then it shows the `https://` but why value='1' it doesnt show `https://`

Comment: `asset()` returns the asset URL according to the current URL scheme by default. You shouldn't have to provide the 2nd argument to do that.

Comment: i dont know why it does not show the scheme by URL of browser:
https://g4u.herokuapp.com/tl for example

Comment: I suppose Heroku does not serve the Laravel application in HTTPS directly. Instead, it's passed through a proxy and then serve that in HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
but why i use `print_r(Request::secure())` in HTTPS scheme, browser shows `1`?

Comment: I'm not sure but I couldn't reproduce the result of `1` with `print_r(Request::secure())` on Heroku regardless of the protocol being http or https. `var_dump` shows that both http and https returns `Request::secure()` as `false`.